# jQuery: "click" param in .on() function bypassed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am learning jQuery animation functions and wirting a small game where the user has to click a moving `div` in a set time frame. The game is writtn so that when the time is up, the final score is displayed and a `div` gives the user the option to "start again" if the user clicks on it.

The problem is with the "start again" `div` that is displayed when the game is over.

Here is the function:

```
function GameOver(){
    $(".game-over").show();
    $("#total-score").text(points);
    $(".anidiv").hide();
    $("#start-again").on("click", Reset());
}
```

And the `div` `$("#start-again")` is referencing:

```
<div id="start-again" class="game-over">
    <img src="Pictures\tryagain.png" id="tryagain">
</div>
```

Through debugging I have found that when `GameOver()` is invoked the first parameter of  `$("#start-again").on("click", Reset());` is bypassed and `Reset()` is called. In other words, `Reset()` is called automatically without the user having to click `$('#start-again)`. So my first go at fixing this was putting `$("#start-again").on("click", Reset());` in `$(document).ready()` but that dosent work either, the user can click on it but `Reset()` does not get called.

It is obvious that the problem has something to do with the position of `$("#start-again").on("click", Reset());` in the script but apart from figuring out the above, I am not too sure where to go from here.

I have published the problem here on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6vLscpt0/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated the fiddle for you. The problem was with your `Reset` function

It should be

```
$("#start-again").on("click", Reset);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6vLscpt0/1/